# (python) meaning of st_mode

Tags: python

Can anyone tell me what is the meaning of the number from the `ST_MODE` function?

Example:

```
>>>import os
>>>stat = os.stat('/home')  
>>>print stat.st_mode  
16877
```

it prints `16877`. What is that for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [standard `stat` module](http://docs.python.org/library/stat.html) can help you interpret these values from `os.stat`:

> The stat module defines constants and
>   functions for interpreting the results
>   of os.stat(), os.fstat() and
>   os.lstat() (if they exist). For
>   complete details about the stat(),
>   fstat() and lstat() calls, consult the
>   documentation for your system.

Answer (score 31):

It's the permission bits of the file.

```
>>> oct(16877)
'040755'
```

See the various `stat.S_*` attributes for more info.

Comment: AFAIK in addition to permissions, st_mode is for testing whether a file is of a specified type (FIFO, link, etc)

Comment: For the lazy: the most significant (leftmost) two octal digits specify file type, the four least significant are of course the normal file permissions bits.  Get these permissions bits with stat.S_IMODE.

Comment: @ACK_stoverflow shouldn't permissions be represented by 3 numbers (owner, group, others) and not 4?

Comment: @robertspierre People usually drop the leading (fourth) octal digit because it's for special things that you normally don't care about - suid, sgid, and sticky bit, and omitting it just means it's zero.  From `man chmod`: `The first digit selects  the set  user  ID  (4)  and set group ID (2) and restricted deletion or sticky (1) attributes.`

Comment: @robertspierre  Use "stat.S_IMODE(mode)" to get the 3 numbers that chmod understands from the mode Python outputs.